# What if I don't agree with edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Being quite new, I try to understand why https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3471109 was rejected.

The reason was: "This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post".

I lost a few hours trying the accepted answer on this post before I found out this didn't work anymore. I made sure I provided all references to backup my edit and to prove it legitimate.

Above all, what frustrates me is the fact that some other users may think this answer is correct and try to apply it when I could have helped.

This question was targeting Ember which is very active and changes quite frequently. I persist to think that this should have been accepted or at least I should know more about the reject.

Also, are the people accepting or rejecting really familiar with the subject?

So many questions I ask myself!

How can I resubmit and disagree with rejection?

Comment: There is no rebuttal for rejected edits. And that edit is rather substantial. Just leave it as a comment. With a bit of luck the (still active) user could include it himself, or address it.

Comment: thanks @Bart! thats what I thought! I really only made this question because I really dont agree. @johnSmith made the point! If you are lucky... it'll go through... though this would be fine if the users that reject had any experience with the subject, this is unfortunatly not the case (in this particular situation)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edits are supposed to fix structural errors, like code formatting, or simple spelling mistakes. You are **not** supposed to make changes to the actual content, even if it's wrong! It is not your answer, it is that given by somebody else. If you want to give a different answer because you feel an existing one is wrong or missing information, you'll have to create your own answer.

[Here is a page with some points about editing.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

Quote (I added the emphasis):

---

Some common reasons to edit are:

- to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes
- to clarify the meaning of a post **without changing it**
- to correct **minor mistakes** or add addendums / updates as the post ages
- to add related resources or hyperlinks

---

However, that is really more a guideline. You can find discussions on Meta about editing policies. In the end, it will always be a subjective process - and that's actually okay. Your edit was likely rejected because it was larger than the entire answer; the same people who rejected it might very well have let it pass if it had been a very long post so that your addendum would have been insubstantial in comparison.